# Has anyone installed Real Player?

Tags: software-installation, 12.10, video-player, unsupported-packages

I have recently defected to Linux from Windows and no regret, almost...

I sort of miss Real Player.  I have found that it IS possible to have it installed which I did through Helix Player website, but this version (RP 11 and Ubuntu 12.10) does not even play DVD.  I know RP is not supported by Ubuntu, but what does this mean exactly?  Is there any way to use Real Player with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Since the RealPlayer 11 package is already available in the [ppa:michael-gruz/backports](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/backports), you can proceed as follows:

1. Create a personal PPA using your Launchpad account.
2. Go to [ppa:michael-gruz/backports](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/backports) and access `View package details > Copy packages`.
3. Select the desired package (say, the one for `Natty`) and copy it to your personal PPA. Change `Destination series` to whatever you need (say, `12.10`/`Quantal`). Ensure that `Rebuild the copied sources` is selected, which will allow the binaries to be built using the available libraries on the chosen distro.
4. Click `Copy Packages`.

These instructions are generic and will work for any package that is already available on a Launchpad PPA, and for any distribution currently supported by Launchpad. They can fail, especially if the chosen distribution does not provide a needed library or a specific version of a library.

But it seems to work in this case. For proof of point, check out the `realplay` that I copied to [my testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/collection). You can check that the package was built against `Quantal` in `View package details` in the `Series` column. (This seems to have worked for the `i386` build, but NOT for the `amd64` one.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Real Player with Ubuntu, the only thing its version 11.  To download it, [click here](http://ubuntuone.com/3pGKECWTHBoEKX5HH5gTnq).

Choose your needed file.  Once downloaded, it will probably be in the downloads folder.  Navigate to the downloads folder, and right click the file, and choose open with Ubuntu Software Center, once you do that and software center opens up, just click on install.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I did exactly this,(as I wrote, I used Helix Player site, but this time through RP site you kindly wrote down) and the end result is the same.  the same RP 11 installed and when I tried to play a DVD, a little window shows up and say "incapable of doing that performance". Is yours working?  This is funny.  If you have any suggestion, please let me know

Comment: The link is dead now. I could only find https://player.helixcommunity.org/ and https://player.helixcommunity.org/2005/downloads/ , but there are no `.deb` downloads available there.

Comment: I found out that real doesn't have the file anymore.  You can get it from [here](http://ubuntuone.com/3pGKECWTHBoEKX5HH5gTnq). I have also fixed the link in the answer.